# Setting Footer or Header in Custom Reader for Spring Batch AggregateItemReader

Tags: spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

I am having difficulty seeing how to set the header and footer for a custom reader that will be wrapped by an AggregateItemReader in Spring Batch.  I want to create a list of 50 or so records to be processed at a time. Does anyone have full example code of using the AggregateItemReader in Spring Batch?

Comment: What do you mean to set the header for a reader? I added an answer with a link to an example of how to skip a header in a flat file. Hope it helps.

Comment: I am specifically trying to create a list of 50 records at a time from an Oracle database.  I want to know how to delimit the records at 50 and send to the processor.  Do you happen to know if this possible with the AggregateItemReader? Thank you for your Answer!

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone have full example code of using the AggregateItemReader in Spring Batch?

You can find an example in the [Multiline sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples#multiline).

In this example, the delegate reader is a [`FlatFileItemReader`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/resources/jobs/multilineJob.xml#L33) on which you can set the property `linesToSkip` to 1 to skip a header.

Hope this helps.